# How to track a new app build in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just want to clear my app's AsyncStorage whenever a new build happens,
is it possible to identify it & perform some actions in react.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your question or not but can't you simply keep a variable that tracks the build and when you update the app simply increment the number.

On each app run check to see if the variable you have in storage is the same and if its not clear the storage and save the new version number.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that how to track new build.

Comment: when you are putting out a new build just increment the variable you are using to track your build number. You want to auto track the build?

Comment: Sorry but this is not the solution, and yes I want to auto track the build.